# What's the default way to create a method alias?

Tags: julia

I have a function like this:

```
function a(s::String; arg1=100, arg2=200)
```

I was trying to find out the default way to create an alias to this function `a`. In other words, to define a function `b` that "points" to function a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something more sophisticated than:

```
const b = a
```

Comment: I highly recommend using `const b = a`.  Otherwise, Julia will have to check every time before using `b` to see if it may have changed and the performance will suffer.